# Erro ao tentar salvar imagem Asp .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Bom dia Pessoal, estou tentando abrir, redimensionar e salvar novamente uma imagem através de uma aplicação ASP .Net porém estou obtendo um erro na hora que a imagem vai ser salva. Segue o código que esta dando erro:

```
public void MudarResolução(string nome)
    {
        string fileName = nome;

        string imagem = string.Format("C:\\Desenvolvimento\\Sistema\\Captures\\{0}.png", fileName);

        try
        {
            Image myImg = Image.FromFile(imagem);

            myImg = resizeImage(myImg, new Size(85, 104));

            myImg.Save(string.Format("C:\\Desenvolvimento\\Sistema\\Captures\\{0}.png", fileName), ImageFormat.Png);



        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }
```

O erro que esta dando na Exception é "Erro Generico GDI+" e da na linha "myImg.Save...", mas não consigo entender o que é. Desde já agradeço a quem puder ajudar.

Outro método que esta funcionando:

```
 public ActionResult Capture()
    {
        if (Request.InputStream.Length > 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream))
            {
                string hexString = Server.UrlEncode(reader.ReadToEnd());
                string imageName = Convert.ToString(Session["Nome_Foto"]);
                string imagePath = string.Format("~/Captures/{0}.png", imageName);

                System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Server.MapPath(imagePath), ConvertHexToBytes(hexString));

                //apenas mostra a imagem capturada na tela a direita
                Session["CapturedImage"] = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(imagePath);

            }
        }

        MudarResolução(imageName);

        return View();
    }

public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
    }
```

Obs: O método "Capture()" salva uma imagem no tamanho 320x240 no diretório "Captures", o que eu quero fazer é abrir essa imagem salva, redimensiona-la (85x104) e salvar a nova imagem no mesmo ou em outro diretório.

Obs: O método "Capture()" esta funcionando, mas não fui eu que o fiz, só fui encarregado de criar esse novo método.

Comment: Verifique se você tem permissões suficientes para salvar os arquivos neste local. Esse é um erro muito comum.

Comment: Você está escondendo a exceção e fazendo nada útil. Todo este código poderia ser só isto: `        var myImg = Image.FromFile($@"C:\Desenvolvimento\Sistema\Captures\nome.png");
        myImg = resizeImage(myImg, new Size(85, 104));
        myImg.Save($@"C:\Desenvolvimento\Sistema\Captures\nome.png", ImageFormat.Png);
` Pode ser simplificando ajude a ver o problema melhor. E poderia dar mais informações. Parece que copiou o código de alguém. Não faça nada no seu código sem entendê-lo. Note que este código que pegou de algum lugar é bem ruim.

Comment: Ola, obrigado pelas respostas, #CaiodePaulaSilva eu possuo permissão para salvar arquivos no local, existe uma outra rotina neste mesmo programa que salva imagens nesta pasta. #Maniero eu simplifiquei o código conforme sua sugestão, continua dando o mesmo erro na mensagem da Exception. E realmente eu peguei o código de outro lugar, eu não sabia como fazer, vou procurar entender melhor.

Comment: @Q.Wesley, você possui permissão... mas o usuário que está executando o serviço? Está no IIS Express, no IIS ?

Comment: Olá @LeandroAngelo, me desculpa, não entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Assim, neste mesmo programa já existe uma rotina que salva imagens em uma pasta, a rotina que postei no tópico pega a imagem que já foi salva e redimensiona a mesma e salva em outra pasta (ali no tópico esta a mesma pasta, mas vou editar),  pelo que entendo o mesmo usuário executa as duas rotinas não é isso? Agradeço sua resposta.

Comment: No código da sua pergunta me parece que você está abrindo um arquivo, editando e tentando salvar ele ainda aberto... Quanto a outra rotina, ela trabalha nesse mesmo diretório? Qual é a procedência do método `resizeImage()` ?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, fiz algumas alterações no tópico dando mais informações sobre o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Recentemente, em uma aplicação de estudos obtive este mesmo erro("Erro Generico GDI+").
A solução foi criar um novo buffer de memória "temporário" para salvar a imagem criada. No meu caso estava trabalhando com formato Bitmap.

```
    //Create Bitmap Image
    var result = //Imagem em formato bitmap


    string outputfilename = string.Format("C:\\Desenvolvimento\\Sistema\\Captures\\{0}.jpg", fileName);

    //SAVE FILE   
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputfilename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
          result.Save(memory, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            byte[] bytes = memory.ToArray();
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
```

Não sei se é uma solução elegante, mas resolveu o erro.